# Skipping the shipping part for custom virtual product

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, shipping

We've a WIP that need virtual products. Not the official plugin, but a custom product type that don’t required any shipping. I was wondering if anyone ever try to do so, and how.

I was thinking about a Switch Field for that particular Product Type that will affect all the checkout process (if no product need shipping in the order, of course) : don't show the "Shipping Address" form, skip the Shipping Method choice and hide any shipping mentions on the order and emails.

Note: I already have a custom module to do custom actions on event for this product type. Extend Craft Commerce is a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution by adding a template variable to my custom module. I can now test from both front-end and back-end if the order really need shipping* with a single `if` statement.

- I split my product types in two segment; physical and virtual, so I can easily loop through my order `lineItems` to look at the product `typeId`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you selling products that are not physical. Just mark the product as free shipping, and skip the address and shipping method selection screens entirely (the front-end is totally up to you).

p.s Product Type settings even have a 'has dimensions' checkbox you can turn off.

p.p.s check out https://github.com/craftcms/digital-products

Comment: The website will also sell physical products, so use the 'Free Shipping' checkbox to this matter is not an option. Free Shipping Products will still need shipping.

p.s. Our "Virtual Product" type is already setup to hide the dimensions/weight fiels.

p.p.s. The "official plugin" I was referring in my question is the Digital Products plugin by the Craft team.